# Wrap highlighted text in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

Is it possible to wrap highlighted text in quotes, brackets, etc. using Pycharm? This is a feature I have seen in many IDEs, but currently when I highlight text and type, e.g., an opening quote, the highlighted text gets replaced by the opening quote instead of wrapping the text in quotes. I can live without this feature, but it would be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can enable this in the settings: Editor | General | Smart Keys | [x] Surround selection on typing quote or brace.